# Can't compile objective c in linux

Tags: linux, objective-c, gcc

I'm trying to get into objective c, but I don't have a mac so I am trying to get it to work on linux. I found these two articles which talk about compiling objective c on linux: [this one](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1064045) [and this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16873844/compiling-objective-c-programs-without-gnustep-on-ubuntu)

Ok, I forgot to say that I don't want to use gnustep, it seems dead and I don't want all the cocoa framework, just the objective c syntax and the c standard library. But I can't compile any code without gnustep!

If I try to compile this code:

```
#import <objc/Object.h>
#import <stdio.h>

@interface Number: Object
{
@public
    int number;

}

- (void)printNum;

@end

@implementation Number: Object


- (void)printNum
{
    printf("%d\n", number);
}

@end

int main(void)
{
    Number *myNumber = [Number new]; // equal to [[Number alloc] init]

    myNumber->number = 6;

    [myNumber printNum];

    return 0;
}
```

I get a segmentation fault, because there's no init nor alloc methods. And if I don't inherit from Object, like so:

```
#include <stdio.h> // C standard IO library (for printf)
#include <stdlib.h> // C standard library
// Interface
@interface test
 -(void)sayHello :(char *)message;
@end

// Implementation
@implementation test
 -(void)sayHello :(char *)message {
  printf("%s", message);
 }

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
 test *test = [[test alloc] init];
 [test sayHello:"Hello world"];
}
```

I get a Bus error. It seems like the only way to create interfaces and implement them is inheriting from NSObject. How can I fix this?

By the way, I'm using gcc with -lobjc flag (with gobjc)

EDIT: ok, so I have to create a root object myself if I don't want to use a framework. How can I do this? I imagine it's something like malloc and free in the init and release methods, but I'm not sure. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

That's not really how Objective C works. You need the runtime, I'm afraid. Many of the good bits of Objective C are about what happens at run- rather than compile-time. If you take away the library, there's not a lot left.

Comment: But, isn't gobjc and libobjc enough then? Libobjc is the runtime library for objective c. Then I guess i'll be using gnustep. (Is it still maintained anyways?)

Comment: @ochi12: You _can_ just use the Objective-C runtime libraries, but then you'll have to recreate a root object with methods like `alloc` and `init` yourself.

Comment: They're pretty tightly coupled, to the point where it's difficult to say what's where (unless you're the maintainer, in which case I'm sure it makes some kind of sense). I'm sure @mipadi is right, but the path of least resistance is certainly just to use GNUStep.

Comment: Looks like commits are still being made to the repository, though I'm not clear how active it actually is.

Comment: So if I implement the NSObject class then I get objective c without the foundation framework? That would be awesome, are there any resources on how to do it?